# GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE was not declared in this scope OpenGL 4.6

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I'm currently programming a simple game in OpenGL 4.6 with FreeGLUT, and I decided to use multisampling to reduce the nasty jaggies, but it didn't work on textures.

So I decided to do

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, texture);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, etc);
```

Instead of

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, etc);
```

*note that I wrote the second snipped by memory, it might be wrong*

But this throws the following errors,

[image: agony]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? As the title stated, I'm using OpenGL 4.6.14757, and FreeGLUT 3.00.00.

Comment: What GL loader are you using (if any)?  Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: You need mipmaping for texture not multisamling. Multisampled textures are useful when rendering to framebuffer.